# chroot into system

Tags: system-installation, grub, raid, software-raid

Update :

Following the advies of slm, I could destroy the RST raid 0 and create a new raid0 using mdadm using the webpage he gave me.
I could start the installation but at the step where grub is installed, I still get an error and installation stop.

When I try to do the step of the webpages below, I get an error while using chroot, telling me that the file or directory doesn't exit despite it does.

Do you have any idea how I can fix this ?

Original :

I need to install Mint on my laptop which has a fake raid0. I tried lots of time and always get an error while installing Grub. I checked on the internet and someone found a solution : after installing Mint as usual, I need to chroot into the system installed on raid. The author give the following link to help : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#ChRoot

The fact is that I just can't apply this solution to my computer. I'm stuck at the step 7 where I need to mount the correct partition. When using the partition GUI tools, I can see 4 volumes : the first one has 3 partitions (one efi, one ext4 and one swap). The 3 others volumes seem to be the 3 partitions of the first volume take one by one. Otherwise, it is asked on the link above to use fdisk, blkid.

The fdisk -l command give me the followind information :

```
Disk /dev/sda: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes

Device Boot       Start         End      Blocks   Id   System
/dev/sda1             1   500130303  250065151+   ee   GPT

Disk /dev/sdb: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/mapper/isw_ecbefbijea_Volume1'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_ecbefbijea_Volume1: 256.1 GB, 256066715648 bytes

Device Boot                           Start        End      Blocks  Id   System
/dev/mapper/isw_ecbefbijea_Volume1p1      1  500130303  250065151+  ee   GPT

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_ecbefbijea_Volume1p1: 537 MB, 537657344 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_ecbefbijea_Volume1p2: 247.1 GB, 247061020672 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_ecbefbijea_Volume1p2 doesn't contain a valid partition table

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/mapper/isw_ecbefbijea_Volume1p3'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_ecbefbijea_Volume1p3: 8467 MB, 8467513344 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_ecbefbijea_Volume1p3 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/sdc: 8004 MB, 8004304896 bytes

Device     Boot  Start       End   Blocks  Id  System
/dev/sdc1     *     63  15631244  7815591   b  W95 FAT32
```

The blkid command give me this :

```
/dev/mapper/isw_ecbefbijea_Volume1p1: UUID="BF26-91E7" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/mapper/isw_ecbefbijea_Volume1p2: UUID="ac1c5978-7533-46b9-87ac-d28b7b8c5453" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/isw_ecbefbijea_Volume1p3: UUID="8c12d467-0b8d-48db-ad69-96f7a23b4ca3" TYPE="swap"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda: TYPE="isw_raid_member"
/dev/sdb: TYPE="isw_raid_member"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="SANDISK" UUID="4208-38E8" TYPE="vfat"
```

Can someone help me to fix this problem ?

EDIT :
This is the parted -l command output :

```
Backtrace has 8 calls on stack :
8: /lib/x86_linux-linux-gnu/libparted.so.0(ped_assert+0x31) [0x7f3d015404b1]
7: /lib/x86_linux-linux-gnu/libparted.so.0(+0x3f5f6) [0x7f3d015705f6]
6: /lib/x86_linux-linux-gnu/libparted.so.0(ped_disk_new+0x49) [0x7f3d0145f99]
5: parted() [0x406dff]
4: parted() [0x407bda]
3: parted(main+0x154b) [0x4065cb]
2: /lib/x86_linux-linux-gnu/libparted.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f3d00d1dec5]
1: parted() [0x406617]

You found a bug in GNU Parted! Here's what you have to do:
....
```

Comment: Rather than mess around with the "fake RAID" I would suggest just using mdadm instead. General steps here: http://www.ducea.com/2009/03/08/mdadm-cheat-sheet/

Comment: Show output of command `parted -l` ran as root.

Comment: @enedil : This is the output I had when I ran as root. I didn't copy eveything after the disk size. If you need them I can add it.

Comment: @slm : So I need to access Intel Rapid Storage and delete the raid ?

Comment: In your post, there is output of fdisk -l, not parted -l

Comment: Yes, then use the HDD's as /dev/sda, /dev/sdb, ... within Linux to construct your RAID there using the software RAID, md, that's included with Linux. I used to use High Point RAIDs long ago and they're nothing but trouble.

Comment: @enedil : I get the following error "Error: Invalid argument during seek for read on /dev/sda". If I ignore these, I get another error : "Error: The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used." I add the output to my post.

Comment: @slm : Weird fact now, I can't access the intel rapid storage program to delete. Usually, I can access it by pressing ctrl+i while booting but now the option doesn't appear. If I set the SATA Mode Selection in the Bios to AHCI will it be ok ?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Do you have enough SATA connections that you do not have to use any that are controlled by the fake RAID controller? If so you can work around it entirely, which is what I would do. If you can't then you might want to try a full-on power cycle to see if you're able to get into it's interface.

Comment: @slm : I don't think so, my computer is an ultrabook so I do not access to any SATA connections :-\ As long as I remember since I could install linux, I don't see the Intel Rapid Storage boot screen anymore.

Comment: I could finally access the Intel Rapid Storage Menu and delete the raid. I will try to create a new raid0 using mdadm :-)

Comment: I have updated the different informations.

Comment: What's the error that you get?

Comment: I don't have any error, the installater just says sthat it has stopped. However, I can say that it stops when it tries to install GRUB. I've checked on Google and it seems that this problem is not so rare.
On the webpage given in my topic, they explain how to reinstall but I getting a problem while mounting the drive (saying that the drive is already mount or /mnt is busy) and chroot says that mnt doesn't exist. I've tried another step by step installation but nothing change, I still get this problem :-\

Comment: Ok, after some research, I think I have an answer to my problem. It seems that Ubuntu has removed raid0 driver. So other distrib like Mint did too.
So, it seems that the only solution is to install the server version of ubuntu and add the desktop package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find a way to make the installation worked.

To explain it briefly, you need to create your partition by using mdadm and gdisk. In my situation, both were not installed on my live USB key. One this is done, I create 2 newt gpt partition table on both disk (sda and sdb). Then I start to create partition on sda. The first one I create is an EFI System partiton (ef02) of 500 MB. Then I create 2 linux-raid partitions (fd00) for the file system and for swap partition.

Then I use mdadm to create two raid partitions and then I use gdisk to create partition table on both raid partitions and then create one partition on both.

Then I start the installation and when you can, choose the manual installation. I can't remember if you need to do something here. At the end, the installation must be done but don't restart your computer.

Download boot-repair and start it. This will ask you to type some command into the terminal. At the end, it will say that something wrong has happened and that you need to restart. Let's do this. If everything worked fine, it should work. In my case, I get an error about diskfilter when my laptop starts.